# Python: How to convert bytes to integer arrays efficiently?

Tags: python, arrays, byte, binaryfiles

I have read a binary file from disk. Which produces a bytes variable e.g.

```py
arr = open(file, "rb").read()
```

Now `arr` is structured such that each 4-byte form a 32bit integer (little endian). I see there is function `int.from_bytes` to convert bytes to int but it is too slow.

Is there a function to convert bytes to an integer array? Numpy solutions welcome.

In contrast, this seems easy to do in R and Julia e.g.

In R

```r
readBin(arr, what="integer", n=length(arr)/4)
```

In Julia

```
reinterpret(Int32, arr)
```

Comment: See Python `array` module.  Format code for 4-byte signed ints is 'l'.  The `.frombytes()` method for what you asked, or the `.fromfile()` method to construct directly by a reading from an open binary-mode file.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Tim Peter's answer it is

```
b = array.array("i")
b.frombytes(arr)
```

Now `b` is an array of int.

See documentation here https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#module-array